# DatePicker source property not updated to null

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datepicker

I have a WPF DatePicker being used in a DataGridTemplateColumn. The DatePicker is bound to a property named StartDate of type DateTime? (Nullable). When I select the DateText in the DateTime picker and delete it, setting the SelectedDate to null, the StartDate property is not being set to null. Do you know why or how to make it bind null values to the source as well as dates?

EDIT: Here's my code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgCampaigns" 
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      RowHeight="22"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      HeadersVisibility="Column"
                      CanUserSortColumns="True"
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                      CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                      BorderThickness="1"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Transparent" 
                      Margin="6,10,6,10" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Campaign Name" Binding="{Binding DislayName}" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="DislayName"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Families Created After" CanUserSort="False">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate, }" Visibility="{Binding Path=startDateEnabled, Converter={StaticResource boolVisibilityConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Enabled" CanUserSort="False">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding Enabled}" Tag="{Binding CampaignID}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate {
        get {
            return this.startDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.startDateField = value;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I've made a little progress, but it is still a mystery. If I explicitly set the UpdateSourceTrigger in the binding to PropertyChanged in my xaml, it works. That is, it will set the property to null when I clear out the date. However, PropertyChanged is already the [DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.defaultupdatesourcetrigger.aspx) for DatePicker.SelectedDate so why does it change the behavior to explicity declare it in xaml?

Comment: I am having a similar issue. If you delete the date then tab out of the date picker the selected date changes but it doesn't fire the setter the selected date is bound to

Answer (score 0):

The default `UpdateSourceTrigger` is `PropertyChanged` for most bindings, however TextBoxes, including DatePicker TextBoxes, are one of the exceptions.

The default `UpdateSourceTrigger` for a `TextBox` is `LostFocus`, because if you are typing a bunch of text, you usually don't want to fire a PropertyChanged event for every key pressed

Comment: Thanks Rachel, but I meant after it loses focus, the property is not updated.

Comment: @xr280xr You mean if you leave it at it's default behavior, change the date, then erase it and Click on another control the value is `null`? (if you're using a key press to process a command, it doesn't trigger the `LostFocus` event)